# RHEL6 Idle Thread Behavior

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, perf

I am doing some cpu performance profiling with the perf tool on a RHEL6 box running weblogic12g.  It looks like the idle threads are presented as native_safe_halt in the stack profile but native_safe_halt is being called by both init and from swapper.  Also, it looks like native_safe_halt is running some of the weblogic JVM processes during idle.  Does anyone have any information on why this occurs in this manner?  Why do swapper and init both have idle responsibilities and what is the difference?
Thank you.[image: Flame Graph]